# How to draw onto a shape that I just drew in Preview.app?

Tags: preview

When drawing using draw tool, if I hover over a shape or image it turns into the hand tool and then I can't draw. How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: pure frustration, innit? Thanks for a good question with an excellent screen recording. I can _feel_ the pain as you're trying to draw on your rectangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Preview app and once the shape is drawn, you can only move, rotate or resize it.

Here is [an article](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/preview/prvwff3ad934/mac) that comes from the Apple's Preview User Guide :

> You can add a shape to a PDF or to an image using the Shapes tool in the Markup toolbar, and then rotate the shape or change its sides or angles.

**If the hand cursor persists or the shape you just drew does not suit you :** click on the *Sketch* or *Draw* button again to draw a new shape.

**If you want to draw onto a shape you have just added :** close the image preview you were editing after saving it and re-open the file so the shape will be considered as part of the image.

Comment: i dont know what it looks like what im asking... but my problem is i do not want to interact with the shape/image there already i want to draw on them. but i can't because even with pen tool selected when my pointer is over them it turns into hand tool and drags them around

Comment: the equivalent of this in photoshop would be to turn off auto select tool.

Comment: i added gif, notice when i hover over box it cursor turns into select tool

Comment: Oh okay, sorry for the misunderstand, I'll edit my answer to be closer to your needs.